# Is juju bootstrap node a single point of failure?

Tags: juju

What happens if I somehow lose my bootstrapped node? Is there a way to make my bootstrapped node HA?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is a single point of failure. We consider HA bootstrap to be the final piece that Juju needs to be considered production ready.

The ability to add another bootstrap node for HA purposes will be in Juju 2.0 this April.

Currently, if the bootstrap node goes away you "only" lose the orchestration, your services and machines stay running, you'll just have to manually ssh from then on. Obviously we want to fix that.

If you have a current working environment the core team has designed in the ability to add-on HA when it lands, so you won't have to tear anything down.  The bootstrap node is the first node that is a state server. You can't add another bootstrap node, but you will be able to add new state servers. This will give HA for the DB, API, and other tasks that currently happen on the initial node.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. If I start using juju now, will I be able to upgrade? Also, is the roadmap available somewhere?

Comment: Yes, you'll be able to upgrade on the spot. Unfortunately no real roadmap past 2.0 is available.

Comment: Warning, name pedantry following: the bootstrap node is the first node that is a state server.  You can't add another bootstrap node, but you will be able to add new state servers. This will give HA for the DB, API, and other tasks that currently happen on the initial node.